# Painfully slow Nessus initialization

Tags: nessus

I have Nessus 5 installed under KaLi.  Whenever I start Nessus (i.e. nessusd), then it takes like half an hour to initialize.  Is there anything one can do to speed up this process?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the Nessus software on a virtual machine, try allocating more RAM to it or else you should check your CPU speed . 2 Ghz or less w ill cause your Nessus to run slow .

Answer (score 1):

i have a core i7 kabby lake 3,8Ghz ddr4 memory an a samsung ssd running nessus on fedora (no vm) it needs 5 minutes to start. It's completily normal the low start on nessus.

Comment: Five minutes is one thing, thirty+ is a complete different issue.

Comment: In tennable forums they say that nessus 6 solves it but i didn't test. Also which HW do you have? Not sure if i have nessus 5 or 6. This afternoon i'll try :)

Comment: To be honest, I am no longer responsible for the Nessus installation and the platform has changed anyway (I posted my question almost three years ago).